# magento , error with the file field in a Form while editing

Tags: forms, validation, magento, input

My form contain a file field for image uploading.

```
   protected function _prepareForm()
   {
       $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
       $this->setForm($form);
       $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('image_form', array('legend'=>'Image  Informations'));

        $fieldset->addField('img_label', 'text',
                       array(
                          'label' => 'Label',
                          'class' => 'required-entry',
                          'required' => true,
                          'name' => 'img_label',

                    ));
        $fieldset->addField('img_src', 'file',
                         array(
                             'label' => 'Upload Image',
                             'class' => 'required-entry',                      
                             'required' => false,
                             'name' => 'img_src',
                            ));

        $fieldset->addField('img_desc', 'textarea',
                    array(
                        'label'     => 'Description',
                        'required' => false,
                        'name' => 'img_desc',
                 ));

        $fieldset->addField('img_link', 'text',
                    array(
                        'label'     => 'Link',
                        'required' => false,
                        'name' => 'img_link',
                ));

 if ( Mage::registry('image_data') )
 {
    $form->setValues(Mage::registry('image_data')->getData());
  }
  return parent::_prepareForm();
 }
```

I only save the file name in my DB, not the whole URL, and whene i'm editing, the field value contain just the image name. If I do not make any changes (image) :

- Magento validation detect the field as empty.

Can you help please !
Thanks

Comment: post the whole `protected function _prepareForm() {` function.

Comment: ok , done. i've posted the function

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `addField('img_src', 'file'...` to

```
$fieldset->addField('img_src', 'image', array(
      'label'     => Mage::helper('tag')->__('Upload Image'),
      'required'  => true,
      'name'      => 'img_src',
));
```

Comment: no ! whene I inspect the page i got this : <input id="img_src" name="img_src" value="C:\wamp\www\magento\media\slider_img\1clown_boom_cover.jpg" class="required-entry required-entry" type="file">

Comment: After saving, what value is in 'img_src' in your database?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'i'm saving just the last part', but the value in you db table should be something like 'catalog/category/1clown_boom_cover.jpg'

Comment: the value in my db  is "1clown_boom_cover.jpg", it's not a product image, but a slider extension.

Comment: I think the problem have to do with where the file is store on the file system. Try manually updating the db and change it `slider_img\1clown_boom_cover.jpg`... if that work then take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931687/addfield-type-image-and-thumbnail-path

Comment: I got the same result ! and i've found this , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903323/cant-get-value-of-input-type-file